# Problema con manage.py al usar runserver

Tags: python-3.x, django

Saludos tengo el siguiente error al ejecutar:

> python manage.py runserver

```
 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
        raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
        from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
        class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
        new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
        value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
        self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
        return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
        backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
        return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 66, in <module>
        check_sqlite_version()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 63, in check_sqlite_version
        raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
        return self.app_configs[app_label]
    KeyError: 'admin'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
        main()
      File "manage.py", line 17, in main
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
        super().execute(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
        self.run(**options)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
        autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
        start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
        reloader.run(django_main_thread)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 272, in run
        get_resolver().urlconf_module
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/manunez/aplication/app/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 256, in inner
        self._setup()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 529, in _setup
        AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
        raise LookupError(message)
    LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
```

El settings.py es:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'e4=_h*!^4zm-(@wimok9=5c4n8gqm#px37-1csz9li(f$0t!uz'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: saludos, agrega como tienes tu **settings.py**  edita tu pregunta para ello aca:  [edit]

Comment: Tienes algún app o algún modelo ?